# Using defines like in C/C++ in C#

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I am working on a project where I need to switch for example between device types. I want to define them  like in C/C++. I found out that this is not possible in C# the same way. I am making some experimental code to learn how it works, but I am stuck on one thing. I've pointed that out in the code below. Please take a look :). I hope the idea of my code is clear, how should I change it to make it work?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        productnames pn = new productnames(); 
        string str = textBox1.Text;
        switch (pn) // I am getting an red line under pn; which says: A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum or corresponding nullable type
        { 
            case DEVICE1:
                label1.Text = str+"CASE1";
                break;
            case DEVICE2:
                label1.Text = str+"CASE2";
                break;
        }
    }
}
public class productnames
{
    public const string DEVICE1 = "name1";
    public const string DEVICE2 = "name2";
    public const string DEVICE3 = "name3";
    public const string DEVICE4 = "name4";
}
```

The code above does not work, because you can not switch between an entire class. A better approach would be something like this:

```
private const string DEVICE1 = "dev1";
private const string DEVICE2 = "dev2";

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = textBox1.Text;
            getCommand(str)
        }

private void getCommand(string Dev)
{
            switch (Dev) 
            { 
                case DEVICE1:
                    label1.Text = str+"CASE1";
                    break;
                case DEVICE2:
                    label1.Text = str+"CASE2";
                    break;
            }
    }
```

This example could be useful:

```
#define CMD_VERSION 0
#define CMD_TYPE 1

private void getCommandName(CMD)
{
   switch(CMD)
   {
      case CMD_VERSION:
      return ("ver");
      case CMD_TYPE:
      return ("serienummer");
   }
}
```

Comment: `productnames` is not a `string`. It _contains_ strings.

Comment: I think you should change `pn` to "be a bool, char, string, integral, enum or corresponding nullable type"

Comment: What type are `SIR80` and `SIR100`? That is the type than `pn` needs to be. That type will also need to be a "bool, char, string, integral, enum or corresponding nullable type" or implicitly convertible to a "bool, char, string, integral, enum or corresponding nullable type."

Comment: Sorry Changed that, forgot to rename those two...

Comment: Ok, then `pn` needs to be a `string`, not a `productnames`.

Comment: Quite simple to solve, "productnames" should be a enum in the way you are using it. (or wanting to use it.)

Comment: Well, in that sample I suspect `getCommandName` returns an integer

Comment: Read about the `switch` statement here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.110).aspx, it escapes me how `#DEFINE` is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be creative and add an example that would be used more quickly in real life.

```
using System;

namespace Draft
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string str = "Device2";
            var strParsed = (Devices)Enum.Parse(typeof(Devices), str);

            switch (strParsed) {
                case Devices.Device1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Device 1");
                    break;
                case Devices.Device2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Device 2");
                    break;
                case Devices.Device3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Device 3");
                    break;
                case Devices.Device4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Device 4");
                    break;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public enum Devices {
            Device1,
            Device2,
            Device3,
            Device4
        }
    }
}
```

[Edit]

Seems i was going in the right direction, only your "define" example give them integer's (which they have anyway on default in the order you have declared them in).

But to follow your example it would be something like:

```
public enum Devices {
    Device1 = 0,
    Device2 = 1,
    Device3 = 2,
    Device4 = 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has nothing to do with `#define`. A `switch` statement cannot operate on an expression, it must be given a literal value (under the hood a switch statement is compiled to an indexed jump table), i.e. it must be a string, int, etc., not an object().

In your case it `pn` seems like `pn` should be a string or enum. Changing your code to this should work:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pn = productnames.DEVICE3; //obviously pn could be set to anything you like, or passed in to the event handler or function
        string str = textBox1.Text;
        switch (pn) 
        { 
            case productnames.DEVICE1:
                label1.Text = str+"CASE1";
                break;
            case productnames.DEVICE1:
                label1.Text = str+"CASE2";
                break;
        }
    }
}

public static class productnames
{
    public string DEVICE1 = "name1";
    public string DEVICE2 = "name2";
    public string DEVICE3 = "name3";
    public string DEVICE4 = "name4";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would say, a dictionary would be a much nicer (and faster) way

```
var Products = new Dictionary<string, ProductInfo>()
{
    { "DEVICE1", new ProductInfo("Properties of product 1") },
    { "DEVICE2", new ProductInfo("Properties of product 1") },
    { "DEVICE3", new ProductInfo("Properties of product 1") }
};


var SelectedProduct = Products[textbox1.Text];
label1.Text = SelectedProduct.Info;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is workaroundable with the following code:

```
   public ProductNames
{
    public readonly static DEVICE1 = new ProductNames("DEVICE1");
    public readonly static DEVICE2 = new ProductNames("DEVICE2");
    public readonly static DEVICE3 = new ProductNames("DEVICE3");

    public string Name{get{return _name;}}  
    private readonly _name ;

    private ProductNames(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }  
}

// usage
ProductNames pn = GetProcuctName(/* your logic */);
switch(pn.Name)
{
    case ProductNames.DEVICE1.Name:
        // do smth
    case ProductNames.DEVICE2.Name:
        // do smth else
}
```